# Fixing masonry opening in chimney for water heater vent

Tags: vent, fireplace, plaster, masonry, chimney

What the right way to fix this? This is the opening to a chimney, for the vent pipe for a water heater. I needed to enlarge the opening from 3 inch to 4 inch. You can see the round part on the left side.

[image: opening for vent]

I was cutting it larger with a hammer drill, and this piece came out (you can see my marking for the new size I need, and the holes I drilled to cut it):

[image: broken piece of plaster and brick]

The back side, has some brick and some plaster (and yes, whoever did this before me stuffed it with newspaper, which can still be read, 20 or more years later):

[image: backside of broken piece]

You can see how the broken piece fits in the wall:

[image: broken piece held near wall]

Should I glue the piece back in? Is there some kind of flat metal plate I can just put over the entire thing? Ignore the broken piece and just rebuild it with plaster?

Comment: Are you running a full pipe vent? If so, is this all just cosmetic?

Comment: @isherwood I'm going stick a 4" metal vent pipe into the (new) hole. The pipe will not go any further than an inch or two into the hole, and after that it needs to be a chimney. (So I do also need to seal the new pipe into the hole.)

Comment: Have you considered the local codes for the venting of gas appliances? Through masonry chimneys?

Comment: +1 on local code, call some well known professionals in your area, and gets quotes. The long term impact, of a failed DIY, is far worse, than the expense of knowing for sure, that it was done correctly, and safely..

Comment: @tahwos I just need to repair some plaster, this is not some complicated project. I am doing what was already there, which was done (badly) by a pro, so I'm not worried about codes - this is the exact same design that is found in homes all over the US.

Comment: @DJohnM Virtually every single house here vents them exactly like this. (And I know because I'm the guy they call when their thermocouple goes out.)

Comment: Anyway I'm not going to redo the plaster - I don't have anything good to put in there to act as a brace to plaster against (I have no desire to copy the pro who used newspaper - and I know it was a pro, I have the receipt). I bought a sheet of metal which I will cut a hole into and glue onto the masonry with Furnace Cement.